# Arrow end points problem

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

I keep getting these circles in my graph and I cannot figure out why. This is the code, is there something wrong with it? Every arrow has a circle at its start and end points and there are also 3 more circles, placed in my graph. I think they are related to the use of the `&` and `&&` symbols, but I cannot understand how or why.

```
\documentclass {article}

\usepackage {amsmath}
\usepackage {amssymb}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin {document}
$\xymatrix{
 & \bullet\\ \bullet\ar[dr]^b_\phi \ar[ur]^a
&& \bullet \ar[ul]^\chi_e   \\
& \bullet \ar[uu]^c_{\psi\circ\chi} \ar[ur]^d_\psi
}\\$
\end {document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I only see four bullet symbols produced by the corresponding `\bullet` commands.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` symbol defines a separator between two points in your matrix. Some of them were missing (which would not disturb) and I added them. The only circles I am seeing right now are the four bullets (replace the command `\bullet` by anything else if you want) and the circle in your middle arrow label `\psi\circ\chi` (you may change to `\times` or `\cdot` or whatever you want to have).

There should be no other circles around. Please see my tidied up example:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all, pdf, cmtip]{xy}

\begin {document}
\[
\xymatrix{
 & \bullet & \\ 
 \bullet\ar[dr]^b_\phi \ar[ur]^a & & \bullet \ar[ul]^\chi_e \\
 & \bullet \ar[uu]^c_{\psi\circ\chi} \ar[ur]^d_\psi &
 }
\]
\end {document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

If you prefer, you may want to do the same graphic with `tikz-cd`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin {document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
{}& \bullet & \\ 
 \bullet \ar{dr}{b}[swap]{\phi} \ar{ur}{a} & & \bullet \ar{ul}[swap]{e}{\chi} \\
& \bullet \ar{uu}{c}[swap]{\psi\circ\chi} \ar{ur}{d}[swap]{\psi} &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end {document}
```